# VB.NET: Audio doesn't start in if Statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, audio

This works:

```
Public Class Form1
Public Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, ByVal hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer



Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim musicAlias As String = "myAudio"
    Dim file As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "tick.mp3")
    If (Not System.IO.File.Exists(file)) Then
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, My.Resources.tick)
    End If

    Dim musicPath As String = "tick.mp3"


        mciSendString("Open " & musicPath & " alias " & musicAlias, CStr(0), 0, 0)
        mciSendString("play " & musicAlias, CStr(0), 0, 0)



    End Sub
End Class
```

While this doesn't:

```
Public Class Form1
Public Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, ByVal hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer



Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim musicAlias As String = "myAudio"
    Dim file As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "tick.mp3")
    If (Not System.IO.File.Exists(file)) Then
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, My.Resources.tick)
    End If

    Dim musicPath As String = "tick.mp3"


        mciSendString("Open " & musicPath & " alias " & musicAlias, CStr(0), 0, 0)
If Label1.Text = "10" then
        mciSendString("play " & musicAlias, CStr(0), 0, 0)
End If



    End Sub
End Class
```

The only difference is that the second part contains an "If" Statements.. Even when it's true the sound is not starting.

PS: It works with *My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.tick, AudioPlayMode.Background)*

Comment: Off-Topic but you should use `file` instead of `musicPath`, `file` contains the full path to the audio file.

Comment: So at the moment I'm just using an extra variable which I don't really need...
Thank you!